# AJAX call from Velocity template

Tags: jquery, ajax, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I have a test webpage which uses jQuery and AJAX to call an ASMX webservice and returns a list of customers in JSON format. The returned data then populates an autocomplete list for an  tag. In the test environment everything works perfectly. I am now trying to get the same code working in JIRA so i can populate a customfield with the list of customers the AJAX call will return, however the AJAX call doesn't work. In my velocity template file i have the following code for the AJAX call:

```
<script>
jQuery("#customfield_10000").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://myserver/jiraservice/ajaxservice.asmx/GetCustomers",
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{inputValue:\"" + request.term + "\"}",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item,
                            value: item
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
});
</script>
```

If someone could please point out how to properly perform an AJAX call from a Velocity template, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it using this kind of code:

```
        AJS.$.get('/rest/api/latest/issue/' + release, {}, function(data) {
            var fields = data["fields"];
            var summary = fields["summary"]["value"];
```

and then make sure that AJS exists with this in atlassian-plugin.xml

JavaScript and CSS files used by Issue Tabs.

```
<dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
<dependency>jira.webresources:jira-global</dependency>

<resource name="issuetabs.js" type="download" location="js/issuetabs.js" />
<resource name="issuetabs.css" type="download" location="css/issuetabs.css" />
```

and make sure that resource gets included using a WebResourceManager

Comment: Hi matt. So im assuming i add the dependencies to the pom.xml? and do i need to download the issuetabs.js and issuetabs.css from somewhere??

Comment: At the moment i have this:
`<web-resource key="autocomplete" name="JqueryAutocomplete">
 <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
 <dependency>jira.webresources:jira-global</dependency>
 <resource name="issuetabs.js" type="download" location="js/issuetabs.js" />
 <resource name="issuetabs.css" type="download" location="css/issuetabs.css" />
</web-resource>`

Comment: Do i now need to add those resources to a 'WebResourceManager' instance in the Java code so that the resources can be accessed in the Velocity template?

Comment: After adding the resources code above to the atlassian-plugin.xml my plugin no longer loads in JIRA...